# getting 400 code while joining discord servers with discord API using requests python

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

## What I'm experiencing:

> While developing a function to join discord servers using Python and Requests module, I keep getting the error code : 400.

## My code:

```py
def joiner():
    invite_code = input("Enter the invite code: ")
    with open('tokens.json', 'r') as file:
        tokens = json.load(file)
        tokens = tokens.get('token',[])
    for token in tokens:
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"{token}"
        }
        url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{invite_code}"
        if "discord.gg/" in url:
            url = url.removeprefix('discord.gg/')

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(f"Token: {token} has successfully joined the server!")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to join the server with token: {token}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

## Traceback:

> `Failed to join the server with token: <token>. Status code: 400`

(Please note that the traceback isn't 100% the real one, there is one modification that I made and it's replacing the real token by `<token>`)

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you should examine the error message that Discord returns in `response.text`, e.g. at the bottom, add:

```py
if 400 <= resp.status_code < 500:
    print(response.text, file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: you're a LEGEND. How didn't I think about this before, it returned: `You need to update your app to join this server.`

Comment: I did some researches, And I found out that hCaptcha blocked me from doing what I want